# F# type error: String vs Async<string>

Tags: types, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first .NET language.

Here is some code I have written so far:

```
let downloadFromWebsite (url: string) =
    async { 
        let uri = new System.Uri(url)
        let webClient = new WebClient()
        let! html = webClient.AsyncDownloadString(uri)
        printfn "Read %d characters from %s" html.Length url
        return html
        }

let results = downloadFromWebsite @"http://plato.stanford.edu"
printf "%s" results
```

Here is the error message:

> ~vs8222.fsx(19,13): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have
>   type
>       string     but here has type
>       Async

What went wrong? What changes should I make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`results` is an `Async<string>` while the format string you're using requires a `string`. You need to run the computation and get the result before you can print it. You can use `Async.RunSynchronously`:

```
let results = downloadFromWebsite @"http://plato.stanford.edu" |> Async.RunSynchronously
printf "%s" results
```

Comment: Thanks, Lee. I have a follow-up question: If I want to write the results into a .txt file, how should I do so? I am not very clear on how to use StreamWriter and etc. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @MY_G - The simplest thing to do is to use [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) if you just wan to write the entire string.